# Cancel/Kill SQL-Server BACKUP in SUPSPENDED state (WRITELOG)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL 2008 R2 Express on which backups are made by executing sqlmaint from windows task planer.

Several backups ran into an error and got stuck in state `SUSPENDED` with wait type `WRITELOG`.

How can I get these backup processes to stop so they release resources?

Simply killing the processes doesn't work. The process will stay in `KILL/ROLL` for a long time. This didn't change for several hours.

Comment: Are you backing up the transaction log or doing a full backup?

Comment: It's a full backup of the database. Recovery Mode is set to `SIMPLE`.

Comment: Honestly that wasn't the answer I was expecting.  A full backup shouldn't be changing much, except switching the changes bit on all the blogs that have changed.  What's the data change rate between full backups?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't get your question. Backup was initiated executing following command from windows shell `sqlmaint -S .\sql2008 -U "sa" -P "..." -D DB -Rpt d:\log\DbBackup2008.log  -BkUpDB D:\Backup\ -BkUpMedia DISK -CrBkSubDir -DelBkUps 1days -VrfyBackup'

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may be related to a SQL Server bug.  Check out this update: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961237

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like it is related since I have a 2008 R2 and am not using a linked server. Nevertheless - thank you.